# gtest setup cmake to get it run

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I want to include gtest to my C++ project. I am using Clion as IDE, which should work. Some tests are already working, but I cannot use any functions from B_RocChoice.h. It says that the function is not declared in this scope.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? How I must change my CMakeLists.txt files that it recogizes my methods?

This is my [basic_tests.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU9IW.png), where my testcases will be written.

This is my [Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyDDS.png).

Here, the most outer `CMakeLists.txt`

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
    project(cli)

    find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
    include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")

    set(SOURCE_FILES
        include/A_WowbaggerChoice.h
        include/AbstractChoice.h
        include/B_RocChoice.h
        include/C_CnnChoice.h
        include/D_DetectorChoice.h
        include/E_LearningChoice.h
        include/Help.h
        include/MyException.h
        include/StartScreen.h
        include/tinyxml.h
        include/types.h
        src/A_WowbaggerChoice.cpp
        src/AbstractChoice.cpp
        src/B_RocChoice.cpp
        src/C_CnnChoice.cpp
        src/D_DetectorChoice.cpp
        src/E_LearningChoice.cpp
        src/Help.cpp
        src/main.cpp
        src/MyException.cpp
        src/StartScreen.cpp
        tinyxml/tinystr.cpp
        tinyxml/tinystr.h
        tinyxml/tinyxml.cpp
        tinyxml/tinyxml.h)

    add_subdirectory(googletest)

    add_executable(cli ${SOURCE_FILES})
    target_link_libraries( cli ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

`CMakeLists.txt` for `gtest`.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)

    project( googletest-distribution )

    enable_testing()

    option(BUILD_GTEST "Builds the googletest subproject" ON)

    #Note that googlemock target already builds googletest
    option(BUILD_GMOCK "Builds the googlemock subproject" OFF)

    if(BUILD_GMOCK)
      add_subdirectory( googlemock )
    elseif(BUILD_GTEST)
      add_subdirectory( googletest )
    endif()

    add_subdirectory(basic_tests)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` for `basic_tests`

```
    include_directories($(gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include    
           ${getest_SOURCE_DIR}))
    #include_directories(../../src/)
    include_directories(../../include/)

    add_executable(runBasicCli
        basic_check.cpp)

    target_link_libraries(runBasicCli gtest gtest_main)
    #target_link_libraries(cli)
```

Comment: Can you fix your links first?

Comment: sry, as new member I only can send 2 links in one post

Comment: Can you reduce the problem to the bare minimum?

Comment: hope you undestand it now better

Comment: Why do you use gtest&gmock in this way? I'm using it in a completely different way: I've built both libraries for my visual studio version and placed it somewhere on the filesystem(not inside the project) and inside the project I use `find_package` for finding gtest&gmock and it is much simpler in my opinion.

Comment: because I work together with several people and we want to have one repository for where everything is inside. Still it does not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your compiler is complaining it can't find the `B_RocChoices.h` header? Your question seems to imply the compiler error is about not finding a function, but `B_RocChoices` is a header and not a function in your `basic_tests.cpp` file.

Assuming your problem is that the compiler isn't finding the `B_RocChoices.h` header, I expect that when you `include_directories(../../include)` you are wanting to make the directory where `B_RocChoices.h` resides part of the header search path. This is a relative path, so it depends where the compiler is being run from as to what path it means (it wouldn't work if you were doing out of source builds, for example). Try using either CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR or CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR to define the path unambiguously. For example:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

If you are using CMake 2.8.11 or later, I'd recommend you consider using [target_include_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) instead and probably also read up on [target_link_libraries()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html). Together, these allow you to make the header search paths and linked libraries specific to a target rather than global to all targets. Lastly, if you prefer to download GoogleTest as part of your build rather than embedding it directly in your project sources, you may find the following link useful:

https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/